# Unable to make items postion relative so they can align each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

i am unable to align two div item next to each other using bootstrap this product detail view where i want to image on left and text on right this is a eccomerce product detail page which i am tryin to create maybe this not the best practise because i am not good at frontend any help will be appreciated

Here is my snippet:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
        $(".tb").hover(function(){
        
        $(".tb").removeClass("tb-active");
        $(this).addClass("tb-active");
        
        current_fs = $(".active");
        
        next_fs = $(this).attr('id');
        next_fs = "#" + next_fs + "1";
        
        $("fieldset").removeClass("active");
        $(next_fs).addClass("active");
        
        current_fs.animate({}, {
        step: function() {
        current_fs.css({
        'display': 'none',
        'position': 'relative'
        });
        next_fs.css({
        'display': 'block'
        });
        }
        });
        });
        
        });
```

```css
    .col-10{
           margin-left: auto;
           margin-right: auto;
       }
       .card {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        }
    
        fieldset.active {
            display: inline-block !important
        }
    
        fieldset {
            display: none
        }
    
        .pic0 {
            width: 400px;
            height: 500px;
            margin-left: 85px;
            margin-right: auto;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    
        .product-pic {
            padding-left: auto;
            padding-right: auto;
            width: 100%
        }
    
        .thumbnails {
            position: absolute
        }
    
        .fit-image {
            width: 100%;
            object-fit: cover
        }
    
        .tb {
            width: 62px;
            height: 62px;
            border: 1px solid grey;
            margin: 2px;
            opacity: 0.4;
            cursor: pointer
        }
    
        .tb-active {
            opacity: 1
        }
    
        .thumbnail-img {
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px
        }
    
        @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
            .pic0 {
                width: 250px;
                height: 350px
            }
        }
        .detail_view{
            margin-right: 100px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid px-sm-1 py-5 mx-auto col-10">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <div class="card col-12">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column thumbnails">
                            <div id="f1" class="tb tb-active"> <img class="thumbnail-img fit-image" src="{{ item.first.url }}"> </div>
                            <div id="f2" class="tb"> <img class="thumbnail-img fit-image" src="{{ item.second.url }}"> </div>
                            <div id="f3" class="tb"> <img class="thumbnail-img fit-image" src="{{ item.third.url }}"> </div>
                            <div id="f4" class="tb"> <img class="thumbnail-img fit-image" src="{{ item.fourth.url }}"> </div>
                          </div>
                        <fieldset id="f11" class="active">
                            <div class="product-pic"> <img class="pic0" src="{{ item.first.url }}"> </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset id="f21" class="">
                            <div class="product-pic"> <img class="pic0" src="{{ item.second.url }}"> </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset id="f31" class="">
                            <div class="product-pic"> <img class="pic0" src="{{ item.third.url }}"> </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset id="f41" class="">
                            <div class="product-pic"> <img class="pic0" src="{{ item.fourth.url }}"> </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="deatil_view" style="float: right;">
                          <p style="color: blue;">{{ item.categories.name}} / <span>{{ item.subcategories.name }}</span></p>
                          <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
                          <p>{{ item.brand_name }}</p>
                          <div class="price">{{item.offered_price|currency}} <span class="actual">  {{item.actual_price|currency}} </span> </div>
                          <strong>About: <br>
                          <span> {{ item.about }}</span></strong>
                          <br> 
                          <strong>Return Policy: <span>{{ item.return_policy }}</span> <a style="border: 1px solid #025; padding:2px" href="#">?</a> </strong>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding two columns in a row :

```
<div class="container-fluid px-sm-1 py-5 mx-auto col-10">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="card col-auto">
                <div class="d-flex flex-column thumbnails">
                    <div id="f1" class="tb tb-active"> <img class="thumbnail-img fit-image" src="{{ item.first.url }}"> </div>
                    <div id="f2" class="tb"> <img class="thumbnail-img fit-image" src="{{ item.second.url }}"> </div>
                    <div id="f3" class="tb"> <img class="thumbnail-img fit-image" src="{{ item.third.url }}"> </div>
                    <div id="f4" class="tb"> <img class="thumbnail-img fit-image" src="{{ item.fourth.url }}"> </div>
                  </div>
                <fieldset id="f11" class="active">
                    <div class="product-pic"> <img class="pic0" src="{{ item.first.url }}"> </div>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="f21" class="">
                    <div class="product-pic"> <img class="pic0" src="{{ item.second.url }}"> </div>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="f31" class="">
                    <div class="product-pic"> <img class="pic0" src="{{ item.third.url }}"> </div>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="f41" class="">
                    <div class="product-pic"> <img class="pic0" src="{{ item.fourth.url }}"> </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="deatil_view">
                  <p style="color: blue;">{{ item.categories.name}} / <span>{{ item.subcategories.name }}</span></p>
                  <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
                  <p>{{ item.brand_name }}</p>
                  <div class="price">{{item.offered_price|currency}} <span class="actual">  {{item.actual_price|currency}} </span> </div>
                  <strong>About: <br>
                  <span> {{ item.about }}</span></strong>
                  <br> 
                  <strong>Return Policy: <span>{{ item.return_policy }}</span> <a style="border: 1px solid #025; padding:2px" href="#">?</a> </strong>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```